# Eclipse RCP javax.net.ssl.setTrustore with p2 doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, p2, truststore

I have a problem that is driving me crazy.
I have an RCP application with p2 that when starts calls a web service (in https) to make login. The certificate is self-signed. Since I don't want to modify jre cacerts I put my custom cacerts in one of my plugin, i extract this plugin using feature function so I have my cacerts on FS and not in a jar.

Before calling WS I set java properties

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","mystruststorepath");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","mystruststorepsw");
```

now the crazy thing.

1. If I run my application from  eclipse IDE everything works fine
2. If I export my application without p2 it works fine
3. If I export my application with p2 it doesn't work and I got an error related to certificate missing in truststore
4. If I run the same application of point 3 just adding in MyApp.ini the option -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mystruststorepath it works

I don't know how this could be related to p2 but the only explanation that I can imagine is that p2 plugin apply some sort of cache of truststore so change it programmatically doens't work. I don't know if this is possibile.

Has anybody run in the same problem?

I want to make evidence of these things

- I configured eclipse jre runtime and execution with the same jre used by the exported product
- I checked more than once the certstore path and it is right

This is the error I got

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Can you check that all certificates from your certificate chains are added to the certificate store. There are sometimes intermediate sign authorities in your certificate chain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I already checked and my cert store contains everything needed. The proof is that it works in cases 1,2 and 4. Just in case 3 it doesn't work...of course the only one I need to!!!

Comment: You could add the truststore argument as ini param via product configuration and add your keystore to the product folder via root file. https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm